# Provider not exported in Delphi SOAP Server + Client

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, datasnap, tdatasetprovider

I'm using Delphi XE7 + Employee Interbase DB.

I'm tryin to build a SOAP server with Datasnap.

I have 3 SOAP Server Data Modules in one server, each one with a table: Customer, Employee, Country, each one made the same way (File, new, other, SOAP Server Data Module), then from Data Explorer dragging a table on the data module (Delphi creates a TSQLCOnnection and a TSQLDataset), then adding a TDatasetProvider. The three Data Modules are identical.

In the client application i have three interfaces made by WSDL importer

```
ICountryWM = interface(IAppServerSOAP)
  ['{1DA001BC-4DFB-E7F8-F62D-DA3545B334DC}']
end;
```

The three interfaces are identical (of course names and GUIDS are different).

In the Client form i have three buttons, they doperform the same operations:

```
procedure TClientFM.BtnEmployeeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet.Close;
  SoapConnection.Close;
  SoapConnection.UseSOAPAdapter := False;
  SoapConnection.SOAPServerIID := '{02E9AB9B-DB17-ACF5-68D9-73FC763C04DC}';
  SoapConnection.URL := 'http://localhost:8080/soap/IEmployeeWM';
  ClientDataset.ProviderName := 'EmployeeProvider';
  SoapConnection.Open;
  ClientDataSet.Open;
end;
```

only changing ServerID, URL, ProviderName.

The three DatasetProvider ini the three Data Module have "Exported" checked.

In the beginning the first SOAP Server Data Module (Customer) worked well: from my client i sawe the Customers table. When i tried Employee or Country, i always got "Provider not exported".

I made a BIG MISTAKE: trying to change something i unchecked the Exported flags, compiled and ran server and client: nothig worked.
Ok, i expected that.
Then I rechecked the flags ... now the Exported flags are checked but no one provider works correctly ... (yes, the one that worked now does not work).

Both Server and Client run in the same PC.

Can someone give me any idea of what is wrong?
I think the problem is in the server, but WHERE in the server?

Comment: The obvious answer is that the server you are connecting to, doesn't have that Provider.